# Is it possible to scrape/download charts in Flash using C#

Tags: c#, flash

I'm trying to scrape content from a webpage. Currently I'm stuck at a place where I want to scrape or download charts. The chart is an SWF object. I need to download the SWF file programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I did this was I found out that the website was passing a csv styled co-ordinates to a chart making service which would then prepare the charts. As I got the input data I was able to construct a chart creation program myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with DownloadFile method of WebClient class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that's possible, but the Flash Player External API is probably a good place to start looking. Here's an example using C# to create flash content through the API:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/flashexternalapi.aspx

You can also take a look at this component:
http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.flash-for-.net/default.aspx